# Flutter build apk target return Couldn't resolve the package

Tags: flutter

im developing flutter project and it work well, i run with my launch.json and it be like

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "music_metric",
            "request": "launch",
            "type": "dart",
            "program": "app/lib/main.dart"
        },
}
```

my project folder structure be like

```
.
├── app
│   └── lib
│       └── main.dart
├── data
├── domain
├── resoure
└── utilities
```

each package will have pubspec.yaml

and my pubspec.yaml in package app will be

```
name: music_metric
description: App module

# The following line prevents the package from being accidentally published to
# pub.dev using `flutter pub publish`. This is preferred for private packages.
publish_to: "none" # Remove this line if you wish to publish to pub.dev

# The following defines the version and build number for your application.
# A version number is three numbers separated by dots, like 1.2.43
# followed by an optional build number separated by a +.
# Both the version and the builder number may be overridden in flutter
# build by specifying --build-name and --build-number, respectively.
# In Android, build-name is used as versionName while build-number used as versionCode.
# Read more about Android versioning at https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/versioning
# In iOS, build-name is used as CFBundleShortVersionString while build-number used as CFBundleVersion.
# Read more about iOS versioning at
# https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=3.0.3 <4.0.0"

# Dependencies specify other packages that your package needs in order to work.
# To automatically upgrade your package dependencies to the latest versions
# consider running `flutter pub upgrade --major-versions`. Alternatively,
# dependencies can be manually updated by changing the version numbers below to
# the latest version available on pub.dev. To see which dependencies have newer
# versions available, run `flutter pub outdated`.
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_localizations:
    sdk: flutter
  configs:
    path: ../../configs
  domain:
    path: ../../domain
  data:
    path: ../../data
  resources:
    path: ../../resources
  utilities:
    path: ../../utilities

  # Override packages
  hive: any
  hive_flutter: any
  get: any
  get_storage: any

  firebase_core: ^2.12.0
  firebase_auth: ^4.5.0
  firebase_analytics: ^10.3.0
  firebase_crashlytics: ^3.2.0

  flutter_loadingindicator: ^1.0.1
  flutter_slidable: ^3.0.0
  flutter_form_builder: ^9.0.0
  form_builder_validators: ^9.0.0
  flutter_pdfview: ^1.3.0
  pull_to_refresh_flutter3: ^2.0.1
  dropdown_button2: ^2.1.0
  percent_indicator: ^4.2.3
  intl: ^0.18.0
  form_builder_image_picker: ^4.0.0
  dotted_border: ^2.0.0+3
  webview_flutter: ^4.2.2
  connectivity_plus: ^4.0.1
  onesignal_flutter: ^3.5.1
  extended_nested_scroll_view: ^6.1.2

  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.5
  flutter_svg: ^2.0.5
  just_the_tooltip: ^0.0.12
  url_launcher: ^6.1.12
  image_picker: ^0.8.9
  image: ^4.0.17
  path: ^1.8.3
  flutter_keyboard_visibility: ^5.4.1
  flutter_staggered_grid_view: ^0.7.0
  permission_handler: ^10.4.3
  regexed_validator: ^2.0.0+1
  flutter_easyloading: ^3.0.5
  persistent_bottom_nav_bar: ^5.0.2
  carousel_slider: ^4.2.1
  expandable_page_view: ^1.0.17
  skeletonizer: ^0.7.0
  collection: ^1.17.2
  card_swiper: ^3.0.1
  image_network: ^2.5.4+1
  just_audio: ^0.9.35
  font_awesome_flutter: ^10.6.0
  audio_video_progress_bar: ^2.0.1
  google_nav_bar: ^5.0.6
  curved_navigation_bar: ^1.0.3
  dio: ^5.3.3
  animated_text_kit: ^4.2.2
  just_audio_background: any


dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

  # The "flutter_lints" package below contains a set of recommended lints to
  # encourage good coding practices. The lint set provided by the package is
  # activated in the `analysis_options.yaml` file located at the root of your
  # package. See that file for information about deactivating specific lint
  # rules and activating additional ones.
  flutter_lints: ^2.0.1

# For information on the generic Dart part of this file, see the
# following page: https://dart.dev/tools/pub/pubspec
# The following section is specific to Flutter packages.
flutter:
  # The following line ensures that the Material Icons font is
  # included with your application, so that you can use the icons in
  # the material Icons class.
  uses-material-design: true

  # To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:
  #  assets:
  #    - assets/fonts

  # An image asset can refer to one or more resolution-specific "variants", see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#resolution-aware

  # For details regarding adding assets from package dependencies, see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#from-packages

  # To add custom fonts to your application, add a fonts section here,
  # in this "flutter" section. Each entry in this list should have a
  # "family" key with the font family name, and a "fonts" key with a
  # list giving the asset and other descriptors for the font. For
  # example:
  # fonts:
  #   - family: Poppins
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: assets/fonts/Poppins-Regular.ttf
  #         weight: 300
  #       - asset: assets/fonts/Poppins-Medium.ttf
  #         weight: 500
  #       - asset: assets/fonts/Poppins-SemiBold.ttf
  #         weight: 700
  #   - family: Cairo
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: assets/fonts/Cairo-Regular.ttf
  #         weight: 300
  #       - asset: assets/fonts/Cairo-Medium.ttf
  #         weight: 500
  #       - asset: assets/fonts/Cairo-SemiBold.ttf
  #         weight: 900
  #
  # For details regarding fonts from package dependencies,
  # see https://flutter.dev/custom-fonts/#from-packages
```

so when i run `flutter build apk -t app/lib/main.dart`
it say

```
Error: Couldn't resolve the package 'data' in 'package:data/data.dart'.
Error: Couldn't resolve the package 'hive_flutter' in 'package:hive_flutter/adapters.dart'.
Error: Couldn't resolve the package 'just_audio_background' in 'package:just_audio_background/just_audio_background.dart'.
Error: Couldn't resolve the package 'resources' in 'package:resources/resources.dart'.
Error: Couldn't resolve the package 'domain' in 'package:domain/domain.dart'.
app/lib/main.dart:1:8: Error: Not found: 'package:data/data.dart'
```

i try flutter pub get but it say it resolved dependencies
how can i solve this

i exptected it will build apk normally and return no error

Comment: Is launch.json necessary in your case?

Comment: @Csisanyi yes, i run by vscode, so i will need it

Comment: update: i solved it by my self by adding package data in pubspec.yaml of project